# Different Results using Simple Linear Regression Packages in Python: statsmodel.api vs sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am hoping to understand why I am getting two different results for a linear regression model prediction. I am using the same data set, and asking for the same value for prediction. I have pasted some example code below, with a link as well to an open Google Colab, [available here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gRkEmSAwLxYMDqXZLu9Mc6V9aVYsteTW?usp=sharing).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model, metrics
import statsmodels.api as sm

temp = [73,65,81,90,75,77,82,93,86,79]
gallons = [110,95,135,160,97,105,120,175,140,121]
merged = list(zip(temp, gallons))
df = pd.DataFrame(merged, columns = ['temp', 'gallons'])

X = df[['temp']]
Y = df['gallons']

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
print("Using sklearn package, 80 temp predicts rent of:", regr.predict([[80]]))

model = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
print("Using statsmodel.api package, 80 temp predicts rent of:", model.predict([80]))
```

With the above code, I receive a result of:
Using sklearn package, 80 temp predicts rent of: [125.5013734]
Using statsmodel.api package, 80 temp predicts rent of: [126.72501891]

Can someone explain why the result is not the same? My understanding is that they are both linear regression models.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Statsmodel doesn't use intercept by default](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) while sklearn use it by default.You have to add intercept manually in statsmodel.

Statsmodel OLS documentation.

> Notes
>
> No constant is added by the model unless you are using formulas.

Sklearn

> fit_interceptbool, default=True Whether to calculate the intercept for
> this model. If set to False, no intercept will be used in calculations
> (i.e. data is expected to be centered).

use `add_constant` function to add intercept to the X and this will give the same results for both algorithms.

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
print("Using statsmodel.api package, 80 temp predicts rent of:", model.predict([1,80]))
```